# Results are not displaying in view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Recently, I discovered that the exam scores of students are not displaying anymore in a particular class (PRE-NURSERY).

Going back to the form where results are added, I see that the results have been repopulated and are already stored in the database. 
[image: repopulated results]

However, they are not been displayed in the view. I wonder what must be wrong.

[image: the view where results are not displayed]

***model***

```
 public function getRecentmtGradesRN($id) 
    {
            $this->db->select('*');

            $this->db->where('student_id', $id);

            return $this->db->get('mtscores_rn')->result();

    }
```

***controller***

```
 public function view($id)
    {

        if (!$this->rbac->hasPrivilege('student', 'can_view')) {
            access_denied();
        }

        $data['title']         = 'Student Details';
        $student               = $this->student_model->get($id);
        $gradeList             = $this->grade_model->get();

         if($class_id == 2 || $class_id == 3)  //see here
        {
            $subjectmtScores = $this->student_model->getRecentmtGradesRN($id);
        }
        else
        {
             $subjectmtScores = $this->student_model->getRecentmtGrades($id);

        }

        $studentSession        = $this->student_model->getStudentSession($id);
        $timeline              = $this->timeline_model->getStudentTimeline($id, $status = '');
        $data["timeline_list"] = $timeline;

        $student_session_id = $studentSession["student_session_id"];

        $student_session         = $studentSession["session"];
        $data['sch_setting']     = $this->sch_setting_detail;
        $data['adm_auto_insert'] = $this->sch_setting_detail->adm_auto_insert;
        $current_student_session = $this->student_model->get_studentsession($student['student_session_id']);

        $data["session"]              = $current_student_session["session"];
        $student_due_fee              = $this->studentfeemaster_model->getStudentFees($student['student_session_id']);
        $student_discount_fee         = $this->feediscount_model->getStudentFeesDiscount($student['student_session_id']);
        $data['student_discount_fee'] = $student_discount_fee;
        $data['student_due_fee']      = $student_due_fee;
        $siblings                     = $this->student_model->getMySiblings($student['parent_id'], $student['id']);
        $student_doc            = $this->student_model->getstudentdoc($id);

        $data['student_doc']    = $student_doc;
        $data['student_doc_id'] = $id;
        $category_list          = $this->category_model->get();
        $data['category_list']  = $category_list;
        $data['gradeList']      = $gradeList;  

        $data['subjectmtScores'] = $subjectmtScores;  //see here
        //var_dump($subjectmtScores); die();       

        $data['student']        = $student;      
        $data['siblings']       = $siblings;
        $class_section          = $this->student_model->getClassSection($student["class_id"]);
        $data["class_section"]  = $class_section;
        $session                = $this->setting_model->getCurrentSession();

        $studentlistbysection         = $this->student_model->getStudentClassSection($student["class_id"], $session);
        $data["studentlistbysection"] = $studentlistbysection;

        $data['guardian_credential'] = $this->student_model->guardian_credential($student['parent_id']);

        $data['reason'] = $this->disable_reason_model->get();
        if ($student['is_active'] = 'no') {
            $data['reason_data'] = $this->disable_reason_model->get($student['dis_reason']);
        }

        // //var_dump($data['teacher_comment']);

        $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('student/studentShow', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);
    }
```

***view***

```
<table class="table table-bordered" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                            <caption class="text-center">ACADEMIC PERFORMANCE</caption>
<thead>
                            <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">

                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;width:120px;text-align:center;">
                                    SUBJECTS
                                </th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid black; font-size:11px;text-align:center;">CLASS
                                    EXPECTATION
                                </th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:11px;text-align:center;">MILESTONE
                                    ACHIEVED
                                </th>
                                <th style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:11px;text-align:center;">REMARKS</th>

                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?php $i = 1;
                            $total = 0;
                            $count = count($subjectmtScores);
                            foreach ($subjectmtScores as $value) { ?>

                                  <?php
                                $mt_tot_score = $value->mt_ca1 + $value->mt_ca2 + $value->mt_ca3 + $value->mt_ca4 + $value->mt_affective + $value->mt_psychomotor + $value->mt_exam;

                                if ($mt_tot_score >= 80) {
                                    $grade = 'A';
                                    $remark = 'EXCELLENT';
                                } elseif ($mt_tot_score >= 70 && $mt_tot_score <= 79.99) {
                                    $grade = 'B';
                                    $remark = 'VERY GOOD';
                                } elseif ($mt_tot_score >= 60 && $mt_tot_score <= 69.99) {
                                    $grade = 'C';
                                    $remark = 'GOOD';
                                } elseif ($mt_tot_score >= 50 && $mt_tot_score <= 59.99) {
                                    $grade = 'E';
                                    $remark = 'PASS';
                                } elseif ($mt_tot_score >= 40 && $mt_tot_score <= 49.99) {
                                    $grade = 'F';
                                    $remark = 'FAIR';
                                } elseif ($mt_tot_score >= 0 && $mt_tot_score<= 39.99) {
                                    $grade = 'FL';
                                    $remark = 'FINAL LETTER GRADE';
                                }

                                ?>

                                <?php
                                $total += $mt_tot_score;
                                ?>
                                <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;text-align:left;height:30px;"><?php echo $CI->GetSubjectNameWithID($value->subject_id); ?></td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->mt_ca1; ?></td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;text-align:center;"><?php echo $value->mt_ca2; ?></td>
                                    <td style="border: 1px solid black;font-size:12px;text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;"><?php echo $value->mt_ca3; ?></td>

                                </tr>
                                <?php $i++;
                            } ?>
                            </tbody style="
    white-space: nowrap;
">
                        </table>
```

Comment: Hey! Does `var_dump($subjectmtScores);` show any data? If yes, please post the output.

Comment: Hello, sorry, you lost me here. How do I do that?

Comment: what's the output of `var_dump($subjectmtScores);`?